# LinkedHashSet does not main insertion order?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, hashset, linkedhashset

I am currently building an Android app where I display quotes from famous people. I have a home screen and 2 other screens, where I am displaying all quotes and the other where I display favourite quotes.

So, when I hit the like button in the screen of AllQuotesActivity the quote and author will be saved in a LinkedHashSet, which will be saved in SharedPreferences, so my FavouriteQuotes Activity can obtain the data. I can obtain the data, but the data is mixed, even though other links say that LinkedHashSet maintains the insertion order. Maybe I did something wrong. Here are the important code snippets:

AllQuotesActivity.java:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_quotes);

    Resources res = getResources();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    this.sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String[] quotesAndAuthors = res.getStringArray(R.array.quotes);

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            set.add(quotesAndAuthors[counter]);
            set.add(quotesAndAuthors[counter + 1]);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("RichQuotes", "Its paused mkay");

    Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

    editor.putStringSet("quotesAndAuthors", this.set);
    editor.commit();
}

}
```

FavouriteQuotesActivity.java:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favourite_quotes);

    Resources res = getResources();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    this.sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    set = sharedPref.getStringSet("quotesAndAuthors", null);

    for (Iterator<String> it = set.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        String s = it.next();
        Log.v("test", s);
    }
```

I removed unnecessary code.

In the FavouriteQuotesActivity.java I am logging the set to check its values. The log-outputs and the outputs on the screen are the same, both unsorted the same way.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could reduce this to a simple block of code, that instantiates a linked hash set, adds some data, and iterates over the set

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I removed unnecessary code

Comment: This is probably unsupported. My guess is, the return value from `getStringSet()` is not a `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Set set = new LinkedHashSet();

In this line, you instantiate a new empty `LinkedHashSet` object. This object was then assigned to the variable named `set`.

> set = sharedPref.getStringSet("quotesAndAuthors", null);

In this line, you reassigned the `set` variable to point to some other object, some `Set` object returned by your call to `getStringSet`. We do not know the concrete class of this second object that implements the `Set` interface. You can ask by calling `getClass`.

Your first set, the empty `LinkedHashSet`, went unused. With no other references pointing to it, that set became a candidate for eventual garbage-collection.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I changed to set.addAll and added the StringSet. However the problem is "getStringSet()" cause it mixes the values from the LinkedHashSet. Any ideas how to overcome this?